# Win7/IIS7 - why does a new Handler Mapping diasappear?

Tags: iis-7, mapping, httphandler

I add a handler mapping to IIS7 (on Win7).  It runs just fine **until** I publish a new build to http://localhost.  Once I publish a new build, all the mappings I added are *magically* gone!!

[EDIT]
I am also losing **all** of my virtual directories during a publish.
[/EDIT]

Any tips/tricks for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handlers are now stored in the app's web.config instead of in the metabase.  Because of that, if you copy out an old copy of the web.config, your changes are lost.

Comment: Oi vay!  So, how do I manage this when we are (1 app) on IIS6 & IIS7 across the dev team?  :)

Comment: It is possible to use this same web.config on an IIS6 server as well.  You have to add an entry to the machine.config to tell it to ignore the new web.config "system.webserver" element.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the system.webServer element of your web.config. One of mine looks like:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```